# Crystal Reports select statement help

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-8.5

I'm attempting to add the MV_AgeBased and the MV_FeeInLieu columns, however some of the columns may have null or empty in the db, this results in bringing back zeroes for that CodeEntity.  Any suggestions?

```
        SELECT "AuditorYearEnd"."PP_MH_Pri", "AuditorYearEnd"."PP_MH_Other", 
"County"."Name", "AuditorYearEnd"."TOTAL_Personal_calc", 
"AuditorYearEnd"."PP_BusPersonal", "AuditorYearEnd"."TaxYr", 
"AuditorYearEnd"."CodeEntity", "AuditorYearEnd"."MV_AgeBased", 
"AuditorYearEnd"."MV_FeeInLieu"
     FROM   "txctr"."dbo"."AuditorYearEnd" "AuditorYearEnd" 
INNER JOIN "txctr"."dbo"."County" "County" ON "AuditorYearEnd"."CodeCounty"="County"."CodeCounty"
     WHERE  "AuditorYearEnd"."TaxYr"=2010 AND "AuditorYearEnd"."CodeEntity"='1010'
```

Comment: Why is this tagged for crystal-reports?  Is this is a data source command for a .rpt?

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT "AuditorYearEnd"."PP_MH_Pri", "AuditorYearEnd"."PP_MH_Other", 
"County"."Name", "AuditorYearEnd"."TOTAL_Personal_calc", 
"AuditorYearEnd"."PP_BusPersonal", "AuditorYearEnd"."TaxYr", 
"AuditorYearEnd"."CodeEntity", "AuditorYearEnd"."MV_AgeBased", 
"AuditorYearEnd"."MV_FeeInLieu"
 FROM   ("txctr"."dbo"."AuditorYearEnd" "AuditorYearEnd" 
INNER JOIN "txctr"."dbo"."County" "County" ON "AuditorYearEnd"."CodeCounty"="County"."CodeCounty"
 WHERE  "AuditorYearEnd"."TaxYr"=2010 AND "AuditorYearEnd"."CodeEntity"='1010')
```

Add "WHERE [column] is not null" for all the potentially null columns?

Not absolutely sure what is being asked, here.